# Excel SUM, FREQUENCY, IF, MATCH

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Why the first formula work and the second formula doesn't, the difference is `AND` condition.

```
=SUM(--(FREQUENCY(IF(J2:J1436>L1,MATCH(A$2:A$1436,A$2:A$1436,0)),ROW(A$2:A$1436)-ROW(A$2)+1)>0))`

=SUM(--(FREQUENCY(IF(AND(J$2:J$1436>L$1,I$2:I$1436<L$1),MATCH(A$2:A$1436,A$2:A$1436,0)),ROW(A$2:A$1436)-ROW(A$2)+1)>0))`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
=SUM(--(FREQUENCY(IF((J$2:J$1436>L$1)*(I$2:I$1436<L$1),MATCH(A$2:A$1436,A$2:A$1436,0)),ROW(A$2:A$1436)-ROW(A$2)+1)>0))
```

Use `*` instead of `AND`.